# Change the color of a part of the text in a textbox

Tags: vb.net

I only know how to change the color of the entire text of a string, instead of a certain part. I want the program to change the color of the word "print", if the program contains "print" and not the entire text.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub codeTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles codeTextBox.TextChanged
        Dim codeInput As String = codeTextBox.Text
        If codeInput.Contains("print") Then
            codeTextBox.ForeColor = Color.Blue
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: VBA????  For VB.NET you might want to look at the FastColored Text box on CodeProject rather than recreate the wheel (and wagon...and barn)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
        If RichTextBox1.Text.EndsWith("Dim") Then
            RichTextBox1.Select(RichTextBox1.TextLength - 3, 3)
            RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
            RichTextBox1.Select(RichTextBox1.TextLength, RichTextBox1.TextLength)
            RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black
        End If
    End Sub
```

Guys it really works i tested on my pc. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim text As String = RichTextBox1.Text
    text = text.Replace(TextBox1.Text, "<font color=blue> " & TextBox1.Text & " </font>")
    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = text
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
End Class
```

[screenshot of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Flg.png)

Comment: This uses a RichTextBox, not a TextBox as the OP specifies.